# jQuery populated datepicker is one month out of sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a script that populates a dropdown selector with dates. It's based on this script: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/curdateform2.shtml

It automatically populates it with today's date.

I have added a custom field in the day and month to allow the user to leave it blank. The addition of the field means that instead of displaying the November, it displays October.

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/87vw93pL/

This is the code:

```
var daytext=['Leave Blank','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25', '26','27','28','29','30','31'];

var monthtext=['Leave Blank','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];



function populatedropdown(dayfield, monthfield, yearfield){
var today=new Date()
var blank="blank"
var dayfield=document.getElementById(dayfield)
var monthfield=document.getElementById(monthfield)
var yearfield=document.getElementById(yearfield)



for (var i=0; i<33; i++)
dayfield.options[i]=new Option(daytext[i], daytext[i])

dayfield.options[today.getDate()]=new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(), true, true)     //select today's day


for (var m=0; m<13; m++)
monthfield.options[m]=new Option(monthtext[m], monthtext[m])

monthfield.options[today.getMonth()]=new Option(monthtext[today.getMonth()],     monthtext[today.getMonth()], true, true) //select today's month



var thisyear=today.getFullYear()
for (var y=0; y<200; y++){
yearfield.options[y]=new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
thisyear+=1
}
yearfield.options[0]=new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true)      //select today's year
}
populatedropdown("daydropdown", "monthdropdown", "yeardropdown")
```

What have I done wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Months are 0 based 0-11 in javascript...

0 - January
11 - December